# Alamofire background fetch doesn't process fruther requests

Tags: ios, swift, background, alamofire

I'd like to perform a background fetch with `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`, obviously all previous solutions didn't worked for me.

The weird thing is my first request are ok, but the next ones aren't.

I tried to use a singleton of SessionManager, I also tried to dequeue all Alamofire requests to a background thread, and changed the `URLSessionManager` with `URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.test.background")`.

```swift
 group.enter()
 api.getClimateStateData(carId: carId, completion: { [weak self] response in
       guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
       climateModel = strongSelf.sortDataFromError(data: response)
       group.leave()
})
```

```swift
func getClimateStateData(carId: Int, completion: @escaping (ServiceResponse<ClimateStateModel>) -> Void) {
        let header: HTTPHeaders = ["User-Agent": UserAgentHelper.fullUserAgentString]
        request("/api/1/vehicles/\(carId)/data_request/climate_state", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: nil, headers: header).responseData { [weak self] response in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            completion(strongSelf.completionResponse(response))
     }
}
```

```swift
    @discardableResult private func request(
        _ path: String,
        method: HTTPMethod,
        parameters: Parameters? = nil,
        encoding: ParameterEncoding? = nil,
        headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
        -> DataRequest {
            let userEncoding = encoding ?? self.defaultEncoding
            print("Asking: " + path)
            return Service.sessionManager2.request("\(API)\(path)", method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: userEncoding, headers: headers).validate()
}
```

I'd like to have those requests fulfilled.

Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was due to `self` = nil.

For some reasons, `self` was deinit.